# Person versus People

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammatical-number

When is the proper time to use the word "persons" in a sentence instead of using "people"?

Comment: This article may help you. http://www.dailywritingtips.com/people-versus-persons/

Answer (score 3):

Michael Swan (Practical English Usage, 2005.524) notes "*Persons* is sometimes used as a plural of *person* **in official language**" (my emphasis added). This supports my own view that we need never use *persons* in our own personal or business life. Leave it for the lawyers and law-makers to write such titles  as The Value Added Tax (Vehicles Designed or Adapted for Handicapped Persons) Order 2001 (found [here](http://uk.practicallaw.com/uklegislation/uksi/2001/754)).

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide any sources (at least, not yet) but you might find this anecdote interesting. I can't vouch for its accuracy, but it does make sense.

My wife is a hotelier, currently as a General Manager, and in that industry they often use *persons*. Naturally, I asked why. The answer I got is that *persons* is used for individuals. "Twenty persons" is twenty individuals who don't know each other. A single group of twenty would be described as twenty people, but the 'people' is usually dropped so it is "a group of twenty". The reason is that groups and individuals are processed differently so they need different terms.

Answer (score -1):

I feel the same as Roaring Fish. When individuality is to be emphasized, I will use persons. If the group is homogenous, I will use people.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that we are not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, but you appear to be posting in support of an existing answer instead of attempting to provide a definitive answer of your own. I strongly advise you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of how the site works, and what goes into an answer.